# screen scraping javascript

Tags: javascript, screen-scraping, screen

so I am scraping javascript from a site and it returns the below code, but if course this will not show the flash video or render the javscript since im just using simple php dom parsers to return the HTML. Is there a way to run this javascript to return the embedded object it outputs?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var attributes = {};
    attributes.id = "flashMovie";
    var flashvars = {};
    flashvars.startjs = "playerLoaded";
    flashvars.activeColor = "83A7D2";
    flashvars.themeColor = "FFFFFF";
    flashvars.config = escape("http://example/0a1cee42025e9e49d25d.fid?key=c3e868caa037531d0d709e238d93013a&VID=189988&catID=1,26,43,50&rollover=1&startThumb=19&embed=&utm_source=&multiview=0&premium=1&country=&user=0&vip=0&heightHD=480p&cd=u&ref=browse");
    //flashvars.config = escape("http://example.com/0a1cee42025e9e49d25d.fid?key=c3e868caa037531d0d709e238d93013a&VID=189988&catID=1,26,43,50&rollover=1&startThumb=19&premium=1&country=&user=0&vip=0&cd=u&ref=browse");
    flashvars.config2 = escape("http://www.example.com/player_feed_local.php?vid=189988&CHIDS=1,26,43,50&link=http%253A%252F%252Fwww.example.com%252Fjump%252FTesting-Video%252Fvideo189988%253Fref%253Dbrowse");
    var params = {};
    params.startjs = "playerLoaded";
    params.loop = "false";
    params.quality = "best";
    params.bgcolor = "#000000";
    params.allowfullscreen = "true";
    params.allowscriptaccess = "always";
    params.wmode= "opaque";
    swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.example.com/Player_v1.11.9.7.swf?v=1.0", "flashMovie", "100%", "500", "9", "expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);
</script>
```

Comment: You mean, return an image representing the object, as if it were on the page?  You can't take something out of its page context reliably.  you will need to render the whole page.

Comment: Which programming language are you using to parse the HTML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run Javascript just like a browser (with a real DOM and all of that) and extract data out using tools like [PhantomJS](http://www.phantomjs.org/) or [Crowbar](http://simile.mit.edu/wiki/Crowbar).

Comment: Huge props for the PhantomJS link. Never seen this and now thinking of some very cool implications.

Answer (score 0):

Use a browser render engine like webkit to execute the JavaScript, and then you can extract the resulting html.

Here is some example code: http://webscraping.com/blog/Scraping-JavaScript-webpages-with-webkit/